# Stereo Images Computer Vision

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I wanted to capture a pair of stereo images with my iPhone camera. I wanted to know how could I do it. What ai have tried so far is, clicked one photo moved my phone a little to the right (almost 1.5 inches), but I did not get the desired results.

I want to rectify those images before I could apply opencv's StereoBM_create function to them. But I can't capture proper stereo images.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not the desired results"? Did you try to rectify the images you have?

Comment: The rectified images were really bad. When I used StereoBM_create function on those, the result was just a black image. Basically, I could not capture good stereo images hence I get bad rectified images.